# Installation Error in DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am new in dotnetNuke. I am trying to install DotNetNuke_Community_05.06.02_Source.zip file.Firstle i extract it to C:\DotNetNuke. There is a release.config file created in C:\DotNetNuke\WebSite\ . Renamed it as we.config. There is another we.config file in C:\DotNetNuke\DotNetNuke_Community_05.06.02_Source\Modules\RazorHost\ renamed it to web1.config. I configured it in IIS6.0 .Created a Database in SQLServer2005 named -DotNetNuke.Changed the connection string as directed by the installation guide. When i am trying to open the installtion wizard through browser it shows an error

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during
>   the processing of a configuration file
>   required to service this request.
>   Please review the specific error
>   details below and modify your
>   configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error
>   to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication'
>   beyond application level.  This error
>   can be caused by a virtual directory
>   not being configured as an application
>   in IIS.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 56:    Line 57: 
>    Line 58:     
>   validationKey="F9D1A2D3E1D3E2F7B3D9F90FF3965ABDAC304902"
>   Line 60:
>   decryptionKey="F9D1A2D3E1D3E2F7B3D9F90FF3965ABDAC304902F8D923AC"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the source package you must compile the code in release mode before attempting to access the website.

Being new to DNN, I recommend starting with the install package which will not need compiled, or even easier, you can get DNN through the Microsoft Web Platform Installer.  WPI will also take care of all the dependnacies that may need configured on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I'ld like to clarify the intention behind downloading the Source Package. Were you intending to start developing and changing the dotnetnuke framework to suit your needs or did you want to set up a website that you could build modules against on IIS?

If you're intending to develop modules, I'ld suggest downloading the Install Package, creating an IIS site under Default Web Site.
- There's no need to change connection strings if you're using the database file that's in the App_Data folder.
- All you need to do is set the Folder Permissions for Network Service or IIS_IUSRS based on what application pool you're running.
- The url to the site will be http://localhost/xxx.

There are 2 ways to build modules in DNN. The Website Project and the Web Application are two different ways. They produce source code and dll's respectively. If it's internal, any way's good. If it's external facing, you might want a little bit more speed, so go Web Application.

However, If you're intending to muck around with the DNN Core Framework and adjust things, the Source is the way to go. there's no need to adjust the settings, just open the website project up in Visual Studio and away you go.